# Using filters in pyGtk

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

I am writing a script to display a GUI in which certain files can be chosen. I am using pyGtk and as of now, my code can display all the zip files. I want to add another filter to display only the zip files with the latest date.

Below is my function that displays only zip files.

```
 def open_file( self, w, data=None):
    d = gtk.FileChooserDialog( title="Select a file",
                               parent=self.window,
                               action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                               buttons=("OK",True,"Cancel",False)
                               )
    #create filters
    filter1 = gtk.FileFilter()
    filter1.set_name("All files")
    filter1.add_pattern("*")
    d.add_filter(filter1)
    filter2 = gtk.FileFilter()
    filter2.set_name("Zip files")
    filter2.add_pattern("*.zip")
    d.add_filter(filter2)


    ok = d.run()
    if ok:
      import os
      fullname = d.get_filename()
      dirname, fname = os.path.split( fullname)
      size = "%d bytes" % os.path.getsize( fullname)
      text = self.label_template % (fname, dirname, size)
    else:
      text = self.label_template % ("","","")
    self.label.set_label( text)
    d.destroy()
```

Is there a way I can choose a filter to display only the latest zip files in a each folder?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `filter2.add_pattern("*.zip")` use `filter2.add_pattern("filename")`where filename is the name of the file with the latest date. You can write a function that would return a list with file names of the latest zip file.